# Prove that P is irreducible with $P(t)=t^{n}-A$

Tags: linear-algebra

$Hello, everyone$ :D , I have this problem

Let $p$ the polynomial $p \in Q[t]$ given by $p(t)=t^{n}-A$ where $A$ is prime. Prove that $p$ is irreducible.

I did this:

Using Eisenstein's criterion:

Let B a prime first:

If B=2 and if divides A finish else (next prime)

B=5 and if divides A finish else (next prime)

B=7 and divides A finish else (next prime)..................

we can ensure that exists a prime B such that B divides A (can be B=A), because B is a prime by the criterion and A too by hypothesis then, **p divides each ai for i ≠ n** this condition is true.

This condition **p does not divide $a_n$** is true because B does not divide 1 then;

**p2 does not divide a0** is easy because, $B^2$ does not divide to A, because A is a prime and $B^2$ is not a prime.

Prove that only p(t) is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and doesn't in general?
Is correct this demonstration?

That for you help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Have a nice day

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion works but you are overcomplicating it. The prime $p$ divides the constant term, $p^2$ does not divide the constant term, $p$ divides each other term expect the leading one (because they are zero), and $p$ does not divide the leading term. These are precisely the hypotheses for Eisenstein, so the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over all primes. Just take $p=A$.

Comment: @Potato ohhh nice "Just take p=A" I said this in my exercise "can be B=A" as p=B then B=A=p, yes I'm overcomplicate this problem but I'm tryed to be especific. Thanks a lot Patato :D and thanks for you help always help me.

Comment: @Potato Can you copy-paste your comments into an answer, so that the question gets removed from the unanswered tab?

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eisenstein's criterion work, but you are overcomplicating it. You don't need to iterate over all primes. Just take $p=A$.

The prime $A$ divides the constant term, $A^2$ does not divide the constant term, $A$ divides the coefficient of each other term except the leading one (because they are zero), and $A$ does not divide the coefficient of the leading term. These are precisely the set of hypotheses for Eisenstein, so the polynomial is irreducible.